# Ajax in for loop increments variable i value to the total length

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

I am developing a ajax upload with progress bar, if the file input isn't multiple there are no problem but I want to develop a multiple ajax upload and for this reason I create a "for" loop until number of files that user has selected.

When the function enters here the value of indice is the value of len variable, why does this happen?

```
 myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) { progressHandlingFunction(e, '.prog'+(indice)) }, false);
```

The complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#uploader').submit(function(){
            var inpf = document.getElementById('files');
            var len = inpf.files.length;
            //console.log(inpf, len);return false;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var indice = i;
                $('div').append('<progress class="prog'+i+'" value="0"></progress><br />');
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', inpf.files[i]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'upload1.php',  //server script to process data
                    type: 'POST',
                    xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
                        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) { progressHandlingFunction(e, '.prog'+(indice)) }, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
                        }
                        return myXhr;
                    },
                    //Ajax events
                    //beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
                    success: function(data){
                        completeHandler(data, '.prog'+i);
                    },
                    //error: errorHandler,
                    // Form data
                    data: formData,
                    //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });

    function progressHandlingFunction(e, klass){
        if(e.lengthComputable){
            $(klass).attr({value:e.loaded, max:e.total});
        }
    }

    function completeHandler(data, klass){
        $(klass).attr({value:0});
    }
</script>
```

Here you have the jsFiddle with the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pgq9s/

Comment: I didn't see any error. Seems to work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `i` is scoped to the entire function, not to a specific iteration of the `for` loop. By the time your `success` callback function is executed, the `for` loop will have executed in its entirety and `i` will be equal to its value after the final iteration (so `i == len`).

Use an immediately invoked function expression to create a closure, preserving the value of `i` for that iteration:

```
for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    var indice = i;
    $('div').append('<progress class="prog'+i+'" value="0"></progress><br />');
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', inpf.files[i]);
    (function(index) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload1.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) { progressHandlingFunction(e, '.prog'+(index)) }, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        //beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: function(data){
            completeHandler(data, '.prog'+index);
        },
        //error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: You could reduce the size of that 'wrapping', and immediately evaluate just to produce the function for the value of the `xhr` property.

Comment: @sje397 The `xhr` function isn't the only one that uses the value of `i`, it's also being used in the `success` callback. Even if that weren't the case, I'm not sure what benefit there would be to reducing it.

Comment: Fair enough. I think for readability you want these things as small as possible. I'd be inclined to even go as far as writing another function taking the index and returning the object that gets passed to `$ajax` - just for readability's sake.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks, it works great but there is a little problem, for some reason if I upload more than 3 images, I check with a console.log the class I receive in the progressHandlingFunction function and I never receive the class ".prog2", it is curious...

Answer (score 2):

The loop starts a lot of ajax requests. Once all the requests are started,  `i` is at it's maximum.

Then the results of the ajax requests are starting to come in and your `success` callback functions are executed. `i` will still be at it's maximum value when all the callbacks are executed.